# Why is Eclipse deleting the CVS directories from my Git cloned repo?

Tags: eclipse, git, cvs

I have a Git repo that still contains old CVS/ directories.  When I create my local clone of this repo and create an Eclipse project pointing at my clone, Eclipse (Kepler SR2) shows all of the CVS/ directories as deleted.  They also show up in the Unstaged Changes list on the Git perspective.

If I do a 'git status' on the command line it shows no modified files.  I need those old CVS/ directories to still be there.  So why is Eclipse doing this and how do I stop it?